# How to avoid SCSS style duplication in insepect time - React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I'm currently working on a **React** project. I'm using **scss mixins** all over my application.

The problem is, I see a lot of style duplication when I tried inspecting my application. I'm assuming this is because I'm importing the global mixins on a number of files all over my application. If so, how can I avoid such style duplication, as I'm worried that this might affect the performance of my application?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**IMAGE :**
[image]

Comment: You have a root `scss` file, import your mixins there or avoid importing in multiple files.

Comment: Sounds like you are importing an scss file that defines some styles into a number of other files.

Answer (score 2):

If you have styles defined for html and body in the scss file then just import the scss file in the root component. This is happening as you might have the imported scss file in multiple compnents there by each time adding styles to html and body.